# C++ Line into Vector

Tags: c++, file, vector, fileinputstream

Wow I've been all over the place with questions today and I apologize if they seem to overlap, but for every question comes another question...Since one thing wont work......but I should use something else......etc.

Anyways, I have a text file:

```
6
3.0 2.5 -1.5 0.0 1.7 4.0
6 10
```

6 is the Number of "floats" in the second line (the 3.0,2.5 etc...)
3.0,2.5,-1.5 are all a series of floats.
6 and 10 are just 2 integers.

I have a Vector

```
std::vector<double> numbers;
```

All i need to do, is get the Second line put into numbers.
So right now I have

```
ifstream myfile (filename.c_str());
```

I can simply just do a myfile>> to get the first value (6)
but how would I go about putting the second line in my vector? Remember I ONLY know how big line 2 is, by reading in the first line (the 6 in this case).

Also the last 2 numbers aren't supposed to be in this vector, but two seperate values.
Which i can just do myfile >> a >> b.

Sorry again for sooo many questions. but I've literally been looking everywhere and asking probably the wrong questions.

Comment: Those are 6 floats, not five?!

Comment: The first line says 6, isn't that a typo?

Comment: Think it is, but its consistent throughout the question, so I thought I'd better ask.

Comment: It's a type. I meant 6 in the later ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like :

```
int count, a, b;
double tmp;
std::vector<double> numbers;
ifstream myfile (filename.c_str());
myfile >> count;
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    myfile >> tmp; numbers.push_back(tmp);
}
myfile >> a >> b;
```

Comment: I ended up using this one this it seemed cleaner. Thanks to everyone that answered tho.

Comment: chrisaycock's solution is better because it doesn't expand the vector unnecessarily. You already know how much space you need.

Answer (score 5):

```
myfile >> numElements;
numbers.resize(numElements);
for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
    myfile >> numbers[i];
}
myfile >> a >> b;
```

Comment: For completeness, can you add int a,b,numElements; declaration and std::vector<float> numbers; declaration as well?

Comment: @Dat I think you just did. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start from the point where you've already read in the line from the file, since it seems like you're OK with that.  This is the most basic approach.  My code below illustrates this approach using very straightforward code that could be used to understand how this works.

1. Get the line you want to parse in to a `string`, this is `line` in my code below.
2. Search the `string` for tokens, where each token is seperated by anything that isn't either a digit, a decimal, or a negative sign
3. For each token, convert the string to a `double` by using `stringstream`.
4. Add the converted double to your vector

At the end of the loop, I also dump the vector to the screen for inspection.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line = "3.0 2.5 -1.5 0.0 1.7 4.0";
    vector<double> doubles;

    string::size_type n_begin = 0;
    string::size_type n_end = line.find_first_not_of("-.0123456789", n_begin);
    while( n_begin != string::npos )
    {
        string cur_token = line.substr(n_begin, n_end-n_begin);
        stringstream ss;
        ss << cur_token;
        double cur_val = 0.0;
        ss >> cur_val;
        doubles.push_back(cur_val);
        // set up the next loop
        if( n_end == string::npos )
            n_begin = n_end = string::npos;
        else
        {
            n_begin = n_end + 1;
            n_end = line.find_first_not_of("-.0123456789", n_begin);
        }
    }

    copy(doubles.begin(), doubles.end(), ostream_iterator<double>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `copy_n()` in your arsenal?

```
template<class In, class Size, class Out>
Out copy_n(In first, Size n, Out result)
{
    while( n-- ) *result++ = *first++;
    return result;
}
```

Put it somewhere where you can easily #include it in other translation units. It's useful. Use it like so to copy your `n` floating-point values:

```
copy_n(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin),
       n,
       std::back_inserter(v));
```